# How can I get click events for items within Listview in CustomAdapter and in the activity where Listview is declared

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, onclick

In my app I am using a ListView which has a customAdapter. In Listview the items are a TextView and a ImageButton. In OnClick event of the ImageButton, I delete an entry in the listview which I have defined in CustomAdapter. In OnClick event of TextView I have start a new activity using Intents. The problem is List.OnItemClick event is not being called in the activity and I cannot start a new Activity in CustomAdapter. How can I get a solution for onClick event of TextView.

Here is part of my code:

In Activity A (in which ListView is present in it's layout)

```
public class RecipientsActivity extends Activity {
....

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REC_INFO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Person new_person = (Person) data.getSerializableExtra("Person");
        Log.e("Before adding", "size = " + recipientArray.size());
        recipientArray.add(new_person);
        Log.e("Add new person", "size = " + recipientArray.size());
        this.m_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,
                R.layout.recipients_list, recipientArray);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rec_list);
        list.setAdapter(m_adapter);
//This event is not being called and I'm not sure if Textview's click event comes here          
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {

                Log.e("Get item clicked", "position may be " + pos);
                Intent rec_Intent = new Intent(RecipientsActivity.this,
                        RecipientAddressActivity.class);
                rec_Intent.putExtra("Recipient", recipientArray.get(pos));
                startActivity(rec_Intent);

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtRecName;
    public ImageButton btn_rec_del;
}

private ArrayList<Person> recipientArray;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Person> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.recipientArray = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int index = position;
    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = vi.inflate(R.layout.recipients_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtRecName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rec_name);
        holder.btn_rec_del = (ImageButton) row
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_rec_delete);
        holder.btn_rec_del.setFocusable(false);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Person p = recipientArray.get(position);
    if (p != null) {

        if (holder.txtRecName != null) {
            holder.txtRecName.setText(p.getName());
        }
    }

    holder.btn_rec_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            //Log.e("Hey","position "+index);
            recipientArray.remove(index);
            notifyDataSetChanged();     

        }
    });

    /*holder.txtRecName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Hola", "hola");
            Intent rec_Intent = new Intent(getContext(), RecipientAddressActivity.class);
            rec_Intent.putExtra("Current_Recipient", recipientArray.get(index));
            startActivity(rec_Intent);

        }
    });*/
    return row;

}

}
```

Here is part of the Layout file of the activity:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/rec_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />
```

ListView's Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/rec_name" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/fill_rece"
        android:focusable="false" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:ems="15"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_rec_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content" android:src="@drawable/ipad_postcare_landscape_from" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: use `holder.txtRecName.setOnClickListener()` in your adapter class

Comment: Why you are calling setOnitemclicklistner inside onActivityResult may be this is the problem. put it outside of the onActivityResult and try...

Comment: when you apply onClickListener in adapter then you get listview item click listener so try implements on click listener one of way 1. declare on click listener in adapter or just implement list item click listener...

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan I have tried that..If you see the code its commented..The problem with holder.TxtREcName.setonclicklistener is I cannot start a new Activity from there. StartActivity cannot be implemented.

Comment: @user2688158 you need context coz startActivity is a method of activity class

Comment: first set context that you passed from activity class in adapter then use `context.startActivity();`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on List item ImageButton takes focus. So add `android:focusable="false"` to `ImageButton` in xml.

Also if you need to use the commented code

```
 Context context;
 public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Person> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.recipientArray = objects;
    this.context = context;  // initialize
}

holder.txtRecName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Hola", "hola");
            Intent rec_Intent = new Intent(context, RecipientAddressActivity.class);
            rec_Intent.putExtra("Current_Recipient", recipientArray.get(index));
            context.startActivity(rec_Intent); 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in getview() use below code at the end of the function.

```
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            //Log.e("Hey","position "+index);
            Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,TargetActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("personData", (Serializable) recipientArray.get(position));
context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

and apply Serializable interface in your Person class.

enjoy.